# Did Muhamad memorize quran?

Tags: quran

[Are there any actual textual differences in Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/are-there-any-actual-textual-differences-in-quran?noredirect=1#comment94058_10582)

One of the answer here says that people that memorize quran often ask Muhamad if they do it correctly and he would "correct" them.

That seems to imply that Muhamad memorize quran? Did he?

Did Muhamad himself a quran memorizer?

Comment: How else would he be able to dictate and teach it?

Comment: Youre right, Muhammad did memorize Qur'an

Comment: and when I say Qur'an, its not the book, its the words itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the sura 87 aya 6

SAHIH INTERNATIONAL

We will make you recite, [O Muhammad], and you will not forget,

سَنُقْرِئُكَ فَلَا تَنسَىٰ - 87:6

There is a hadeeth saying that Gabrial was reviewing  the Quran with the prophet each year once but last year of his life they reviewed it twice 
 أسرَّ إلي -تعني أن أباها حدثها سراً فقال لها- إن جبريل كان يعارضني القرآن كل سنة مرة، وإنه عارضني العام مرتين، ولا أرى الأجل إلا قد اقترب